# Is it possible to extract the symbol out of swf file which was downloaded using URLLoader (and not embedded))

Tags: actionscript-3, embed, urlloader

I am trying to download a heavy swf dynamically to my site using URLLoader class. I'd like to know if it is possible to use a symbol inside the swf as a separate object?

The code used right now uses the embed statement as follows:

```
[Embed(source="/Fight.swf", symbol="Kungfu")] 
public class Kungfu extends MovieClip
{ ... }
```

Embedding the swf increases the initial load time of my site and I want to make it dynamic. How can I access the Kungfu symbol from Fight.swf after it is downloaded using the URLLoader class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to get the class definition from the loaded SWF. Few months ago I summarized the process [here](https://taskinoor.wordpress.com/2011/02/06/as3-load-assets-dynamically-for-better-performance-2/). The example used bitmaps, but you can use movie clips as well.

Answer (score 0):

... Why not use [SwfLoader](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/controls/SWFLoader.html)? It's Flex native. If you're not in Flex, why not use a [Loader](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/Loader.html)?

Either way, I don't think that URLLoader is what you really want here.

Comment: Thanks :) I shouldn't be using URLLoader. I'm not on flex, but I use flex builder for development. So I'll go for using the Loader class. Can you please tell me how I can use a symbol from the loaded swf file and use it as an object in my project?